# Store procedure select returns null after insert

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables called tipo_produto & tipo_veiculo and tipo_produto_veiculo

Basicaly, a procedure called addTipo_produto that inserts values into tipo_produto and then selects tipo_produto to get the last ID where the values match but it returns null and it's impossible because I just added the value before

```
DELIMITER //
Create procedure addTipo_produto(
    IN p_tipo_produto varchar(50),
    IN p_tipo_veiculo varchar(50)
)
begin
DECLARE id_tipo_veiculo INT; 
DECLARE id_tipo_produto INT; 
INSERT INTO `tipo_produto`(`tipo_produto`) VALUES(p_tipo_produto);
SELECT `id_tipo_veiculo` INTO id_tipo_veiculo FROM `tipo_veiculo` WHERE `tipo_veiculo` LIKE p_tipo_veiculo;
SELECT `id_tipo_produto` INTO id_tipo_produto FROM `tipo_produto` WHERE `tipo_produto` LIKE p_tipo_produto;
INSERT INTO `tipo_produto_veiculo`(`id_tipo_produto`, `id_tipo_veiculo`) VALUES((SELECT(id_tipo_produto)), (SELECT(id_tipo_veiculo)));

end//
DELIMITER ;
```

Entire code:
https://pastebin.com/0qWgtusK

Fixed code:

```
DELIMITER //
Create procedure addTipo_produto(
    IN p_tipo_produto varchar(50),
    IN p_tipo_veiculo varchar(50)
)
begin
DECLARE _id_tipo_veiculo INT; 
DECLARE _id_tipo_produto INT; 
INSERT INTO `tipo_produto`(`tipo_produto`) VALUES(p_tipo_produto);
SET _id_tipo_veiculo = (SELECT `id_tipo_veiculo` FROM `tipo_veiculo` WHERE `tipo_veiculo` LIKE p_tipo_veiculo);
SELECT `id_tipo_produto` INTO _id_tipo_produto FROM `tipo_produto` WHERE `tipo_produto` LIKE p_tipo_produto;
INSERT INTO `tipo_produto_veiculo`(`id_tipo_produto`, `id_tipo_veiculo`) VALUES(_id_tipo_produto, _id_tipo_veiculo);

end//
DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: Use `LAST INSERTED ID` instead. Try `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`

Comment: @Rohit.007 now the id_tipo_veiculo returns null also

Comment: There is no insert statement for `id_tipo_veiculo`

Comment: @Rohit.007 it-s added previously on another procedure

Comment: You mean in different query just before it? Is it in the `transaction` have you commited the statement?

Comment: @Rohit.007 before I call addTipo_produto() I call another procedure add adds values to the table tipo veiculo

Comment: is it reflected in the table?

Comment: @Rohit.007 https://pastebin.com/0qWgtusK this is the entire code, the selects on the addTipo_produto return null and I don't know why

Comment: You need to answer few queries. 1. Have you checked the value reflected in `tipo_veiculo`? 2. are you using `DB Transaction`? 3. have added try catch for any error ?

Comment: As presented, that proc will always return null; only `SELECT` statements that are not `SELECT INTO` and are not `SET x = SELECT ...` are returned. Otherwise, the main issues I see are stylistic (variable names that are identical field names are confusing at best, and `VALUES(SELECT(x), SELECT(y))` is just complicates `VALUES (x, y)` with no benefit)

Comment: Also, the `SELECT INTO` queries do not guarantee singular results; if they have multiple, it will be an error.

Comment: Having the same names was the reason it returned null thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

I have altered one line because only insert statement was for `tipo_produto` table.
Hope rest can be done by you.

```
DELIMITER //
Create procedure addTipo_produto(
    IN p_tipo_produto varchar(50),
    IN p_tipo_veiculo varchar(50)
)
begin
DECLARE id_tipo_veiculo INT; 
DECLARE id_tipo_produto INT; 
INSERT INTO `tipo_produto`(`tipo_produto`) VALUES(p_tipo_produto);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO id_tipo_veiculo;
SELECT `id_tipo_produto` INTO id_tipo_produto FROM `tipo_produto` WHERE `tipo_produto` LIKE p_tipo_produto;
INSERT INTO `tipo_produto_veiculo`(`id_tipo_produto`, `id_tipo_veiculo`) VALUES(id_tipo_produto, id_tipo_veiculo);

end//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You don't need `SELECT` in the `VALUES` list. Just `VALUES(id_tipo_produto, id_tipo_veiculo)`

Comment: You should avoid using variable names that are the same as column names.

Comment: Can you accept the answer and vote-up if this helped?